# Context não carrega os dados do Banco

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf

O meu context não esta trazendo os dados do banco.

Mensagens de erro.

> Valor não pode ser nulo.
>
> "Valor não pode ser nulo.\r\nNome do parâmetro: connection"
>
> Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: connection

Cód conection string Business Entity

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ASCSEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Cód conection string WPF

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ASCSEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Criação do Contexto:

```
 public partial class ASCSEntities : DbContext
{
    public ASCSEntities()
        : base("name=ASCSEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olhando para as imagens dá perfeitamente para ver o erro... Posta o código da tua conection string, para ver se ao menos é possível ajudar em alguma coisa...

Comment: Olá. Não coloque imagens, coloque o código ou a descrição do erro. Quando trocar eu retiro o -1.

Comment: Obs.: A string de conexão eu estou passando dinamicamente.

Comment: @Jhonas seria uma boa ideia, à entrada do método que vai criar o `context`, verificar a `connection string`. Investigue o método que está a chamar o método onde a excepção ocorre.

Comment: Eu verifico o conexão toda vez que eu faço o login, tanto que se que se a conexão estiver com erro eu sou encaminhado para uma tela de configuração.

Comment: @Jhonas acho que precisaremos de mais contexto. Coloque o código que cria o contexto e o código que chama o método que cria o contexto por exemplo. Quando disse verificar, queria dizer verificar se não é nulo, vazio ou espaço em branco.

Comment: Eu estou achando isso muito estranho, já tinha acontecido isso de não carregar o contexto e depois voltar, agora voltou a carregar sem eu achar oque realmente ocasionou essa falha.. Esta funcionando tudo certo agora, mas eu ainda não sei oque ocasionou isso!

Comment: Será que pode ser alguma configuração? Eu não alterei praticamente nada e agora não esta carregando o contexto novamente, eu alterei um store procedure, será que pode ser algo relacionado a atualizações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser as aspas duplas neste trecho
`provider connection string=&quot;` e neste `App=EntityFramework&quot;`. Mude para aspas simples.

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/ASCSEF.csdl|res://*/ASCSEF.ssdl|res://*/ASCSEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string='data source=10.000.000.00;initial catalog=ASCS;user id=XX;password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'"
```

Comment: Como eu estou passando a minha conection string dinamicamente eu retirei esse cód do app.config, tanto na camada de negócio quanto na do WPF ficou assim:
<add name="ASCSEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: mesmo assim ainda nao funciona? E o Provider do WPF não é "System.Data.SqlClient"?

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou. Eu acredito que o provider seja o System.Data.EntityClient mesmo, eu alterei para me certificar mas deu erros na criação do contexto.

Comment: tenta colocar nomes diferentes nas conexoes @Jhonas

Answer (score 1):

Você deve colocar a ConnectionString tanto no WPF quanto no seu Business Entity, quando você compila, o .config que predomina é da última camada da aplicação que provavelmente é o WPF.